# Angular: How to refresh view from another scope?

Tags: angularjs

Problem:
I have a simple registration form. After new user does an Authentication my application gets him to a new link but do not show a new page with content and do not switch ng-if in the views. So the View doesn't refresh(but everything is fine when I push F5 button), I've tried to refresh it, but don't actually understand what I need to run

Registration form:

1. service `Authentication`. Method that set the data to the `localStorage` and transfer to a new link:

```js
 Authentication.registration = function(data) {
   localStorage.setItem('registrationData', JSON.stringify(data));
   $location.path('/userPage');
 }
 Authentication.ifLog = function() {
   // verify if the user exists in localStorage
 }
```

2. popup login form and it's `directive`(with it's own scope) method in the `Link` function:

```js
 $scope.registration = function(form) {
     Authentication.registration(
     };
```

3. And this is all for switching the menu and transfer to user page. When user logIn we show him first and third menu and transfer him to a new page. 
   '`Base`' - it's a controller where I call `ifLog` method from `Authentication` service

```html
<li ng-if="Base.logined"><a href="#userPage">UserPage</a></li>
<li ng-if="!Base.logined" ng-click="Base.toggleModal()">LogIn</li>
<li ng-if="Base.logined">{{Base.user.name}}</li>
```

What should I do to update the view?

Answer (score 0):

your variable is updated in controller, but not in view. You can use [scope apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to update variable in view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I've tried to use apply, but it seems to me that I did it in a wrong place. I've try to use scope.apply in my directive scope. As I understand I need to use in my Base controller but I don't run any methods from that scope after registration. How should I use it?

Comment: if you logined variable is in wrong place you can use $rootScope, but it's not clean way.

Comment: I don't want to use rootScope, I'm learning Angular and want to learn it in best way :)  . No, 'logined' var in the main Base controller, but service methods I run in my directive with isolated scope, so the Base controller doesn't refresh. If I do $scope.apply() i'ts doesn't work in my directive scope, I should do $scope.apply(and something is here)  in my directive or main Base controller?

Comment: Base controller and $rootScope semantically is same. Both of them contrary principe of encapsulation.
ok there is another cleaner way. You can make $rootScope.$apply() in your service, where 'logined' is changed.